# What are the hardware requirements for building and developing Strongbox?

Tags: hardware, strongbox

I am a university student, looking to do some OSS work in order to practice in Software Engineering. I would like to ask what are the hardware requirements for building and developing [Strongbox](https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/), as I couldn't find any information in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your interested in our project! We should indeed add pages to [our documentation](https://strongbox.github.io/) regarding both the required runtime and development hardware resources.

I would recommend the following, if you'd like to be able to build things in reasonably short times:

- At least 16 GB RAM
- An Intel i7 processor (or equivalent)
- An SSD

Of course, you can get by with less than that, but your build times with all unit and integrations tests would be significantly higher. A typical build with all unit + integrations tests (executed with `mvn clean install -Dintegration.tests`) should take between 8-16 minutes depending on your hardware.

Of course, you can work only on the modules you're interested in, but, in the end you will still have to build the entire project along with all tests.

For more details, please feel free to join our [chat channel](https://chat.carlspring.org/).